# How to reset ether balances of accounts in Ganache UI?

Tags: ganache

I tried the restart option but it doesn't change anything
[low balance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkRns.png)
[restart option in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHaAn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hey there same issue here.
Restart option is for restarting the Ganache not to reset the balances to 100 ETH.
So to get all accounts back to 100 simply create a new workspace and use it.
I think it is easier.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an option to reset the state to zero or effectively delete all blocks. Having to delete and create new workspace is meh.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here with the non-functional reset button in the Ganache GUI.  Don't know how to reset yet but I found a temporary work around (at least until the Ether runs out of all 10 accounts!)

Connected both the seed account (seed) and the receiving account (rcvg) to MetaMask and then sent rcvg the funds in seed. Worked even with 0 WEI to pay for gas!